# How to solve this compilation warning? (Format specifier issue)

Tags: c, casting, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have this code:

```
PRINT_VALUE("Displaying value: %x",A->B.C.D);
```

D is of type unsigned short.

```
#define  PRINT_VALUE(Name,Val)    \
    if(Val){fprintf(fp,Name,Val);fprintf(fp,"\n");}\
    else {fprintf(fp,Name);fprintf(fp,"\n");}
```

Even if I use %d and cast A->B.C.D to int, the same warning persists. Any help?

Warning message:

> warning: format ‘%x’ expects a matching ‘unsigned int’ argument
>   [-Wformat]

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with macro expansion. I had a similar code.

```
#define fp stdout

#define  PRINT_VALUE(Name,Val)    \
    if(Val){fprintf(fp,Name,Val);fprintf(fp,"\n");}\
    else {fprintf(fp,Name);fprintf(fp,"\n");}

int main()
{
        short D = 0;
        PRINT_VALUE("Displaying value: %x", (unsigned int)D);
}
```

This macro expands as follows

```
int main()
{
    short D = 0;
    if((unsigned int)D)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Displaying value: %x",(unsigned int)D);
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Displaying value: %x"); //<-- the warning is here
        fprintf(stdout,"\n");
    };
}
```

The `else` part also requires an argument. Probably that is not what you want your macro to do.

Comment: I just want to print the value. Could you please help me modyfing the code?

Comment: You can modify the `else` part in the macro to use `fputs`. but this is just a work around. Like `else {fputs(Name, fp);}`. This is just to skip the *warning*.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you please explain briefly why fputs doesn't give a warning while fprintf does?